# Remove all non-numeric characters from text files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to remove all non-numeric characters from a bunch (~2000) of .txt files.

For example, file1.txt:

```
Sydney  33
Castle hill  47
Lake's town hill  79
```

should become, file1.txt:

```
33
47
79
```

I want to change the content of each text file, not print the output on screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^[:digit:]]\+//g'
```

- `[^[:digit:]]\+` matches one or more (`+`) non-digits (`[^[:digit:]]`) and we're replacing that with empty string, globally (`g`)

Use `sed -i` (or `sed -i.bak` for keeping the original with a `.bak` extension) for in-place editing of the file.

---

Same thing with `awk`'s `sub(Regex, Replacement, Input)` function:

```
awk 'sub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", $0)'
```

Use `--inplace` for in-place editing of the file.

---

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                 
Sydney  33
Castle hill  47
Lake's town hill  79

% sed 's/[^[:digit:]]\+//g' file.txt               
33
47
79

% awk 'sub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", $0)' file.txt
33
47
79
```

Comment: thanks, I like this but I don't want to print the output on screen, I want to change the content of each txt file - thanks for your help

Comment: @user2861089 "Use `sed -i` (...) for in-place editing of the file."

Answer (score 1):

With `tr` (and assuming you don't want to remove newlines)

```
$ tr -dc '[0-9\n]' < file1.txt
33
47
79
```

Given the structure of your file, you could also use `awk` to print the last whitespace-delimited field:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file1.txt
33
47
79
```

Comment: thanks, I like this but I don't want to print the output on screen, I want to change the content of each txt file - thanks for your help

Comment: @user2861089 in that case I would choose one of the `sed` variants (although recent versions of GNU awk aka `gawk` can also do in-place edits)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$ echo "Jim 5" > file.txt
$ echo "Jane 3" >> file.txt
$ sed -i 's/[^0-9]//g' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
5
3
```

Using your test data:

```
$ cat file1.txt
Sydney 33
Castle hill 47
Lake's town hill 79

$ sed -i 's/[^0-9]//g' file1.txt

$ cat file1.txt
33
47
79
```